# SQL Server DB table data size query result not increasing if data count increasing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, insert, bulk-insert, database-size

I have a query which will show the Table Name, Number of Rows and Size of the record of a Database tables in SQL Server. when I executed the query I got a result showing

```
TableName            NumberOfRows   SizeinKB
TBL_PROCESS_AUDIT2   1              16
```

But When I inserted more record into the same table using the same insert query and executed the query, it showing more number of rows (50) but the same size (16kb).

```
TableName            NumberOfRows   SizeinKB
TBL_PROCESS_AUDIT2   50             16
```

Actually when the number of rows of a table is increasing, it's size also should increase. So for 1 record the size is 16KB so for 50 records, the size should be 800KB. When I inserted bulk record like some 2000 records, the size is varying.

What would be the logic or problem in my query? I want the actual size of the records of a DB table.

**My Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE #RowCountsAndSizes (TableName NVARCHAR(128),rows CHAR(11),      
       reserved VARCHAR(18),data VARCHAR(18),index_size VARCHAR(18), 
       unused VARCHAR(18))

EXEC       sp_MSForEachTable 'INSERT INTO #RowCountsAndSizes EXEC sp_spaceused ''?'' '

SELECT     TableName,CONVERT(bigint,rows) AS NumberOfRows,
           CONVERT(bigint,left(reserved,len(reserved)-3)) AS SizeinKB
FROM       #RowCountsAndSizes 
ORDER BY   NumberOfRows DESC,SizeinKB DESC,TableName

DROP TABLE #RowCountsAndSizes
```

Comment: Try running DBCC UPDATEUSAGE.  See the remarks on this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQL Server stores data on 8kb pages. You can't have a table that's smaller than than two pages. So when you add one row to the table, you have a minimum space consumption of 2 * 8kb = 16kb. But those pages aren't full, which means adding 15 more rows doesn't increase table size by (15 * initial size), it just means that the data page holding the initial row had enough room for more data. If you add 1000 more rows, I bet your size will increase, but this will vary depending on what's in a row and how many rows can fit on an 8kb page.

I don't know that it matters, really, how much data is in a table if you want to only look at the space on a page that's used, and ignore the space on a page that isn't used. You're taking 8 kb on disk and 8 kb in memory whether the page has 10 bytes of data or 7,997 bytes. So you will see that most space calculation scripts just take `(number of pages) * 8,192` because the unused space on a page is very rarely relevant.